# How to model a table to save many metrics for same timestamp in QuestDb?

Tags: data-modeling, questdb

I have zillion lot of sensors which tick every min with some floating point data and I want to use to save the data in QuestDb. I see two options:

Options 1 is to create a wide table with zillion of columns and have one row per each minute

```
| Time  | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | .... | Sensor1232123 |
| 10:01 |     3.4 |     0.0 | .... |          23.4 |
| 10:02 |    5.46 |  23.987 | .... |           0.0 |
...
```

And the option option 2

```
| Time  |     Id |  Value |
| 10:01 |      1 |    3.4 |
| 10:01 |      2 |    0.0 |
...
| 10:01 | 123123 |   23.4 |
| 10:02 |      1 |   5.46 | 
| 10:02 |      2 | 23.987 |
... 
| 10:02 |      3 |    0.0 |
...
```

Since my data comes from individual sensors independently I'm inclined to use option 2 but the QuestDb requires the designated timestamp column to be ascending, so I cannot have duplicated values in `Time` column.

It sounds pretty common case but I cannot figure out how can I store my sensors data in one table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **option 2** you described where there is timestamp, sensor id, value saved in the table.

Repeated timestamp is allowed so it is valid to have all the sensors as individual rows at 10:01, 10:02 etc.